# Debugging JavaScript object references

Tags: javascript, debugging, javascript-debugger

I've got two variables pointing at the same object. At some time one of the variable changes its reference to another object.

Are there any debugging tools or techniques to find out place where the link breaks?

Comment: Please post all your code so we can have a better idea of whats going on. aside from that I'd advice putting console logs in different places and also using something like chrome dev tools to set break points at certain points to check the code there

Answer (score 0):

You can set a breakpoint in your Chrome developer tools under the Sources tab. When this code is reached, you can see the current scope and all its variables/values on the right hand side under the Scope panel. Then just navigate through the functions using the controls above it and see when the values change.